# How to pass a variable number of arguments (lists) to a function to create an array out of these?

Tags: python, arrays, function, variables, multidimensional-array

For example, I have the following function:

```py
import numpy as np

def CreateBoxes(x_1: list, x_2: list):
    boxes = np.array([[y , z] for y in x_1 for z in x_2])
    return boxes
```

Which may return something like this:

```
[[[0.  0.5]
  [0.  0.5]]

 [[0.  0.5]
  [0.5 1. ]]

     ...

 [[4.5 5. ]
  [4.5 5. ]]]
```

However, I would like to extend this for multiple variables. For example, `x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4` et cetera.

I know it is possible to define a function using `*args` to include multiple variables. But I can't figure out how to adapt the rest of my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for `itertools.product`?

Comment: @timgeb And maybe `*args` as the function parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, `itertools.product` does what I need. However, when I try to create a function

`def CreateBoxes(*args):`
    `boxes = itertools.product(args)`
    `return boxes`

I don't get the result I'm trying to get. Whereas, I do get the result I want when I do `boxes = itertools.product(x_1, x_2, x_3)`.

Comment: You need to unpack `args`: `boxes = itertools.product(*args)`. Although it seems like you don't have to define a new function: `CreateBoxes = itertools.product`.